# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input Angular 6 and RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

In Angular 7, I was trying to create a custom Aysnc validator which checks van item already exists or not and if exists it will show error as part of form validation.

```
validate(
    ctrl: AbstractControl
  ): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return this.itemService.isItemExists(this.listId, ctrl.value).pipe(
      map(isExists => (isExists) ? { alreadyExits: true } : null),
      catchError(() => null)
    );
  }
```

And my .itemService.isItemExists() methods as below

```
isItemExists(listId: string, itemNumber: number) {
    const url = "http://localhost:41469/isValid?listId='abc'&itemNumber=6";
    return this.http.get<boolean>(url);
  }
```

Don't mind URL, It is proper in my code. But getting error

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input,  Array.map ()...."

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Could u share your imports which you have in this component? I think it's mistake related with RXJS/Operator import

Comment: Unrelated but `catchError(() => of(null))` needs to return an observable.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` this is a **syntax error** it means that the TypeScript compiler sees something wrong with the source code. For example; you are missing a close bracket on a code block. I see no syntax mistakes in the code you provided, but try using an IDE like Visual Code or WebStorm as they find these mistakes while you are typing.

Comment: Yes I have imported properly, also my editor have TSLint and not giving any errors.